# JavaFX custom TextField restriction

Tags: java, javafx, textfield

I'm making an application for my math teacher to convert a plane from its vector equation form to its scalar equation form.

For my input TextField I have this code.

```
TextField input = new TextField();
input.setPromptText(" (x,y,z) + q(a,b,c) + p(a,b,c) ");
```

I want to restrict the input to the given format (Restricting input format in general).

The only way I could think of doing this, would be to have a thread or action listener constantly calling

```
input.getText();
```

Then comparing every index of the string to see if it is the correct type of input (Is a number, or is a bracket... etc).

This seems like a very "noobish" way of doing it... Does anyone know of a better way of doing this? Perhaps java has some built in methods for it?

Comment: You might want to consider using a mix of multiple text fields and labels rather than a single parsed text field value.

Comment: That was what I was going to do originally, but then I would end up with 9 different text fields. This project is not so much to just achieve the purpose, but also a learning experience. @jewelsea

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You can use **controls FX** validation support to make this work :

**In your controller u can set validator to your text field:**

```
validationSupport = new ValidationSupport();
        validationSupport.registerValidator(textField, true, ValidationForm.formatValidate);
```

**Then you can design your validator as you need inside a separate class:**

```
public class ValidationForm {

    /**
     * Field allows only if correctly formatted
     */
    public static Validator<String> formatValidate = (Control control, String value) -> {
        boolean condition = value != null
                ? !value.matches("^\\({1}+[0-9]+\\,[0-9]+\\,[0-9]+\\){1}+\\+{1}"
                        + "+[a-z]{1}+\\({1}+[0-9]+\\,[0-9]+\\,[0-9]+\\){1}+\\+{1}"
                        + "+[a-z]{1}+\\({1}+[0-9]+\\,[0-9]+\\,[0-9]+\\){1}$") : value == null;

        return ValidationResult.fromMessageIf(control, "Not a valid input \n"
                + "Should be formatted \" (x,y,z) + q(a,b,c) + p(a,b,c) \"",
               Severity.ERROR, condition);
    };
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Look into the 3rd party Controls FX library which features [validation/decoration](http://fxexperience.com/controlsfx/features/#decorationvalidation) of input controls and for which you can [createRegExValidator](http://controlsfx.bitbucket.org/org/controlsfx/validation/Validator.html#createRegexValidator-java.lang.String-java.util.regex.Pattern-org.controlsfx.validation.Severity-).  Use [regex101](https://regex101.com) to fashion your regex.  Once validation passes, you can use [pattern matching](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/) on the regex to retrieve the input values from the input string.

As this is mainly a learning exercise for you, I won't supply the code for this at the moment.

Comment: Went to regex101 and created this, "\(\d,\d,\d\) \+ [a-z]\(\d,\d,\d\) \+ [a-z]\(\d,\d,\d\)" not sure where I go from here.